# No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Django Postgresql

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get the average of a field in my model but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
function avg(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AVG("home_course"."course_difficulty") AS "course_dif...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This is my model field I am getting an average on:

```
class Difficulty(models.TextChoices):
    EASY = '1', 'Easy'
    MEDIUM = '2', 'Medium'
    HARD = '3', 'Hard'
    FAILED = '4', 'Failed'
course_difficulty = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=Difficulty.choices,
    default=Difficulty.MEDIUM
    )
```

And I am using this query:

```
avg = Course.objects.filter(course_code=self.course_code,course_university=self.course_university).aggregate(Avg('course_difficulty'))
```

(`course_code` and `course_university` are both CharFields)

Now after searching I came to realize that it's possibly because `course_difficuly` is a CharField, how can I convert it to integer without losing my text choices? Can I simply change it to IntegerField?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) django database function

> class Cast(expression, output_field)
>
> Forces the result type of expression to be the one from output_field.

---

Something in the line of following

```
avg = Course.objects.filter(
        course_code=self.course_code, 
        course_university=self.course_university
).annotate(
    course_difficulty_int=Cast('course_difficulty', IntegerField()
).aggregate(
    Avg('course_difficulty_int')
)
```